# why most linux distro have 7 tty and make x window to tty 7 as default?

Tags: linux, tty

I know tty can be reduced but I don't know why Most linux distro have 7 tty(s) as a default setting.

Why choose 7 instead of 6 or 3? I had never use all 7 tty at the same time.

And, The reason for move X window to tty 7, Two guesses:

For convenient purpose,

To use all tty?
Users prefer to start a small order of tty first?

Comment: Hello Richard, SU is to find solutions to technical issues, rather than for discussions, please read the [faq]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many releases ago, when people used floppy disks and wrote their own modelines, it was quite common to accidentally break or misconfigure X11, and have various manual pages open in all six ttys while trying to fix it.

Today, I'm guessing it's just out of habit – many users are used to having first 6 ttys to be available for text login, because that's how Linux worked for many years. This is also in various documentation and tutorials.

However, Fedora has recently [decided](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/DisplayManagerRework) to put X11 on the first tty (vc1).